# Why is SQL strict about clause order?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, language-design, grammar, clause

This works:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id LIMIT 5
```

This doesn't - throws a syntax error:

```
SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 5 ORDER BY id
```

SQL seems to be too strict about clause order.

Does it have a good reason to be that strict?

*P.S.* SELECT and FROM specify the source of the data and I agree that this should have a specific position in the query. The other clauses, though, just "play" with that data - they have a relationship with the source of the data, but not with each other so the fact that they should be ordered in a particular way doesn't seem very intuitive to me.

Comment: Every language has a defined grammar.

Comment: So that you don't have to remember the order of the clauses.

Comment: @Emanuil for some reason you don't like the design decisions. Instead of accepting they don't work as you would like them, you try to argue they are wrong. You seem to have made up you mind, even before you asked the question.

Comment: You think `SELECT` and `FROM` are in the right order? I think you're in the minority there (quite apart from output being one of the last stages of the query processing, it also makes it a pain to try to implement Intellisense in a sensible way)

Comment: @Jacco, I wouldn't say I don't like the design decisions. I'm just curious about the reasoning behind them. I argue not because I want to prove a point, but rather to provoke a discussion that would give me a better understanding of the question.

Comment: @Martin, that's true. Another true thing is that there are reasons for the grammar to be the way it is. These exact reasons are what this question is about.

Comment: @Emanuil That was hardly clear from the first version of your question.

Comment: you understand what am do I about writing? bet not you I do. why need grammar is we that. (do you understand what I am writing about? I bet you do not. That is why we need grammar.)

Answer (score 6):

Hugh Darwen theorizes that it was fashionable for languages to be this way in the 1960s:

> Do you take SELECT-FROM-WHERE for
>   granted, or do you, like me, find it
>   rather curious that the System R team
>   should have spurned the normal way of
>   writing expressions of arbitrary
>   complexity in favour of something
>   utterly idiosyncratic and, one might
>   say, rather dictatorial...?
>
> The fact is that in the 1960s various
>   scripting languages (as we tend to
>   call such things these days) had come
>   about for the purposes of report
>   generation, especially ad hoc report
>   generation.  We had one such language
>   in the prerelational DBMS called
>   Terminal Business System (TBS) that I
>   worked on for IBM from 1969-77.  Our
>   language required the user to specify
>   the required report in a series of
>   steps that had to be given *in the
>   prescribed order*...
>
> A somewhat similar but much more
>   sophisticated report generator was
>   later developed by IBM in the US, as
>   part of a product called (prosaically,
>   as was IBM's style in those days)
>   Generalized Information System
>   (GIS)... when I first looked at SQL,
>   my immediate reaction was  "Oh no! 
>   Son of GIS?  Please not that!"  I
>   might have been quite wrong about
>   this.  The similarity I perceived
>   might have been illusory and even if
>   it was not, I have no firm evidence
>   that anybody in the System R team was
>   familiar with GIS.  The fact remains
>   that the general style of a fixed
>   order of actions was the order of the
>   day at the time.  I postulate that
>   SQL's SELECT-FROM-WHERE arose out of
>   this fashion.

From [`HAVING` a Blunderful Time](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/HAVING-A-Blunderful-Time.html)

Comment: @Brian White: "I have no firm evidence..." -- IIRC Darwen has since found some quite compelling evidence, alas I was not able to keep my review copy of the article and I forget now where it was published!

Answer (score 2):

When you write in english or another language, you also use a specific grammar. 
You never put the verb at the end of the sentence in english but it is used in german.

In SQL, it's the same there is a syntax you have to respect.
You also don't write a query like that `FROM user SELECT * ORDER BY xy WHERE a=b`

Comment: Sure, but if you have to describe a couple of things in an English sentence, it's up to you to decide the order in which you are going to describe them.

Comment: Of course... But your are also free to describe order of things in couple of part of a SQL query: 
- Between `SELECT` and `FROM` 
- The order of clauses in `WHERE` part

Comment: And that's good, right? If SQL can be flexible about that, why can't it be flexible about the clause order?

Comment: Of course, yes! But if you are totally flexible with part (SELECT, FROM, WHERE, ORDER,...) order it will be harder for other person to read you. eg. you'll write all the time with a specific order, someone will write all the time in a different order, I'll write with my order sometime and sometime I'll change, etc.. With a fixed order for part, it's easier for everyone to learn an order and to quickly read and understand what another person write.

Comment: SELECT and FROM specify the source of the data and I agree that this should have a specific position in the query. The other clauses, though, just "play" with that data - they have a relationship with the source of the data, but not with each other so the fact that they should be ordered in a particular way doesn't seem very intuitive to me.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is MySQL's syntax:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: MySQL does not have a syntax. It's SQL that has a syntax and the question is not whether something is SQL's syntax or not. It's bout the reasoning behind the design of that syntax.

Comment: Actually you are wrong. This is a MySQL syntax. for example the same thing in MSSQL can be accomplished with the TOP keyword placed in front of the select columns. And as for the reasoning of designing a syntax I can give a few reasons: 1. easier to parse a line if you know from the beginning the structure of it. 2. easier for someone to understand someones code if the syntax is fixed, and not to search in one guys mind.

Comment: And if the code is not structured according to a syntax then code writing would be a mess, code practices would be written and we would end up writing in one way cause is the accepted way. So is easier for them (who made it) and for use, for that syntax to be enforced.

Comment: MySQL is a RDBMS, SQL is a language. The SQL syntax that MySQL supports is different from the SQL syntax that MSSQL supports, but this doesn't mean that MySQL is a language.

Comment: well I was less focused on the grammar and more to give you an answer. When I said MySQL syntax, I was referring to MySQL specific SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The parser is built for speed. If you allow inconsistant syntax, the parser takes more time to figure out what needs to be done. This can have a significant impact on performance.

Also, it makes it easier for humans to read.

Comment: I agree it would require some computing but it shouldn't require too much computing. I doubt the impact on the performance would be significant.

Comment: The impact will not be significant until you run a high-traffic system. Then, all the sudden all those little insignificant steps add up and cause a huge load.

Comment: OK, but then why is SQL not strict about everything? For example, why does it allow omitting the quotes for integers in WHERE clauses - `id = '5'` works the same way as `id = 5`?

Comment: @Emanuil, They are not the same. The first is typecasted, the second is about integer comparison. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html

Answer (score 0):

LIMIT aside (it's TOP in SQL Server for example), there is a logical processing ORDER for SQL statements that reflects the syntax order

1. FROM
2. WHERE
3. GROUP BY
4. CUBE/ROLLUP
5. HAVING
6. SELECT
7. DISTINCT
8. TOP/LIMIT
9. ORDER BY

if you substitute LIMIT with TOP then it quite obvious

Comment: Not really. Why would `SELECT` be written first if the syntax reflected the logical processing order? By that logic we would write `FROM users SELECT * DISTINCT LIMIT 5 ORDER BY id`

Comment: @Martin: which is approaching LINQ2SQL syntax... no? I have no problems with SQL synatx anyway :-)

Comment: I assume your `9. ORDER BY` is for final result ordering, and you're hiding the other use of `ORDER BY` (for determining which rows qualify) inside `8. TOP/LIMIT`?

Comment: @Martin: Maybe also because lots of languages, particularly dating from the era when SQL was designed, begin each statement with a key word saying what it will be doing? It makes parsing a lot easier; the parser knows what it can expect to follow, and if that is not found, then it is an error.

Answer (score -1):

First and foremost, let me tell you

> "Every language has its set of rules & regulations "

We need to follow this rules. Breaching of any kind of rules (e.g syntax) of any of the command will lead us to error.

---

Use the `ORDER BY` clause to specify the order in which cells on the left-hand side of the rule are to be evaluated. The expr must resolve to a dimension or measure column. If the `ORDER BY` clause is not specified, the order defaults to the order of the columns as specified in the `DIMENSION BY` clause.

Check out here for more :

- [Order By Clause (a)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2171079)
- [Order By Clause (b)](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db29.doc.sqlref/db2z_sql_orderbyclause.htm)